# Deciding non-isomorphic subgroups of symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

Is there a good way to tell whether two subgroups $G$ and $H$ of some symmetric group $S_n$ is isomorphic? It comes to my mind that this can be done via the cycle types of elements in $G$ and $H$. In particular, I have the following

> **Conjecture**: If $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic then there is an element of either $G$ or $H$ such that no element of the remaining group has the cycle type of that element.

The conjecture basically comes from the way one typically attempts to find Galois group of some field extension. How can one approach this kind of problem?

Comment: IIRC the number of elements of each cycle type determines a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ up to conjugacy for $n \le 7$ but not for $n \ge 8$. (So you can find Galois groups using this fact for polynomials of degree $\le 7$ but not in general.) I don't remember where I read this and can't find a reference though.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. What about $n=4$, $G$ being the group of all double transpositions together with the identity, and $H$ being a subgroup of $H$ of order $2$?

They both contain only the identity and double transpositions, but they are not isomorphic...

Comment: @verret: your comment does settle the question negatively. Why don't you post it as an answer? (BTW that group will be an *avatar* of the Klein's 4-group)

Comment: Deciding whether two (finite) groups $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic is a difficult problem in general. The fact that they are both subgroups of $S_n$ is not particularly helpful in solving this problem except in so far as it facilitates computation in $G$ and $H$ as abstract groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest counterexample is when $n=4$: take $G$ to be the group of all double transpositions together with the identity, and $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$ of order $2$.

If you want examples where both $G$ and $H$ are transitive, then the smallest examples are for $n=8$: up to isomorphism, there are three groups of order $8$ and exponent $4$. ($C_4\times C_2$, $D_8$ and $Q_8$.) Let $G$ and $H$ be two such groups, non-isomorphic, and consider their regular representation. It's easy to see that the cycle types represented in both cases will be exactly $1^8$, $2^4$ and $4^2$.